# I am getting patsy error because of the formula i used while implementing OLS Regression

Tags: python, linear-regression

I am trying to predicting Car sale for which i m using OLS Regression.
i have  got list of some important features using F regression which i m using as part of the formula
my formula looks something like this:

```
myformula='ln_Interest_Rate~Engine_size+Fuel_efficiency+Horsepower+Q("Latest_Launch_1/15/2011")+Q("Latest_Launch_10/21/2011")+Q("Latest_Launch_11/28/2012)+Q("Latest_Launch_12/10/2011")+Q("Latest_Launch_12/20/2011")+Q("Latest_Launch_12/21/2012")+Q("Latest_Launch_2/25/2012")+Q("Latest_Launch_2/27/2012")+Q("Latest_Launch_3/17/2011")+Q("Latest_Launch_3/6/2012")+Q("Latest_Launch_4/25/2012")+Q("Latest_Launch_5/20/2012")+Q("Latest_Launch_5/31/2011")+Q("Latest_Launch_6/29/2012")+Q("Latest_Launch_7/1/2012")+Q("Latest_Launch_7/11/2011")+Q("Latest_Launch_8/16/2012")+Q("Latest_Launch_8/17/2011")+Q("Latest_Launch_8/6/2011")+Q("Latest_Launch_8/7/2011")+Q("Latest_Launch_9/1/2011")+Price_in_thousands+Sales_in_thousands+Vehicle_type_Passenger+Wheelbase+four_year_resale_value'

model = smf.ols(my_formula, data=train).fit()
print(model.summary())
```

This throws me error saying:

```
PatsyError: numbers besides '0' and '1' are only allowed with **
```

Kindly suggest the way I can get rid of this error.

I have used `Q()` also but it does not solve my problem